# Can the default View settings for Spotlight "Show all in Finder" be changed?

Tags: finder, spotlight

When doing a Spotlight search (in OSX 10.14.6), I often click on "Show all in Finder" to see more results.  The resulting Finder winder is always grouped which is not my default Finder window setting and which I rarely want.  I have to go the View menu to unselect "Use Groups" every time.  My regular Finder windows do remember my View settings. Is there any way to change the default View settings for the Finder window produced by Spotlight "Show all in Finder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It doesn't seem possible

Notice that when you switch to Finder search, the `View > Show View Options` does not display the option to set window viewing defaults like a regular Finder window does **(a)**:

[image]

[image]

If you find the search inadequate and not just a cosmetic irritation, it may be useful to further refine your Finder search with additional filters that can be accessed from the filter buttons **(b)** or directly in the search bar.